# Graphs where same-colored edges can not cross.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

We say that a graph is $k$-planar if there you can the draw the graph in such a way that you can color the edges in such a way that no edge crosses an edge of the same color. For example a $1$-planar graph is just a planar graph.

My question is, how do you determine if a graph is $k$-planar?

The case for $k=1$ is already known.

Comment: Not to be confused with [this kind of 1-planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph), which allows at most one crossing of edges (in that situation, a planar graph is a 0-planar graph).

Answer (score 1):

This is the [thickness of a graph](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Thickness_(graph_theory)), and determining it is NP-hard.